# Is it possible to check the values and position of an Array against the values and position of an arraylist

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList`,

```
private List <Guess> guesses = new ArrayList<>();
```

and an `Array`,

```
public PegEnum code[] = new PegEnum[4];
```

is it possible with using 2 `for` loops

```
for(int i=0; i<=code.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<=guesses.size(); j++ ) {

    }
}
```

to compare the values and position of the `ArrayList`  to the values and position in the `array`?

`code[]` is filled with `PegEnum` objects
`guesses` is filled with `Guess` objects

Comment: They have same or different sizes?

Comment: how are Guess and PegEnum related ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you have problems accessing the `ArrayList` at a certain index? Do you have problems comparing the `PegNum`s to the `Guess`es? Please specify your question.

Comment: i have problems connecting the PegEnums to the Guess